Dynamic route for LoginPage in security configuration
I have a multilingual login form. The multilanguage is handled by a custom LocaleInterceptor. The language is the first part of the RequestURI:: /{lang}/foo/bar
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/{lang}")
public class SecurityController {
    @GetMapping(value = "/login")
    public String login() {
        return "security/login";
    }
}

Is it possible to use a placeholder in the path of the LoginPage? Example:
.formLogin(login -> login
    .loginPage("/{lang}/login")
    // ...
)

My research has shown that this is not possible and that I need to exclude the LoginPage from the LocaleInterceptor and use a separate locale handling, for example via a GET parameter: (/login?lang=en).
Or is it possible to manipulate the path via an event/listener?

If all your URLs are in the same format I would use an URL RewriteFilter to remove the /{lang} part and store it somewhere else.

All routes have the language as the first part. I will use the SessionLocaleResolver for the login page and save the language accordingly in my custom LocaleInterceptor. Then I will also have the language on the login page.

The rewrite filter can help you with that. See https://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/ for instance or if you have an NGINX or Apache Http server you can configure that to do the same.
